# CSV file data export using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I am having data in mysql table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `camp_expense` (`expense_id`, `camp_regtype`, `camp_name`, 
       `camp_date`, `expense_name`, `expense_amount`, `expense_total`, 
       `calculation_date`, `expense_status`) VALUES (1, 'Free', 'Sharekhan', 
       '2012-07-27 10:05:pm', '["Petrol / Conveyance"]', '["1000"]', '1000', 
       '31-07-2012 ', ''), (2, 'Free', 'Sharekhan', '2012-07-27 10:05:pm', 
       '["Tea / Water","Staff Incentives"]', '["1000"," 10000"]', '11000', 
       '31-07-2012 ', ''),
```

In this the 5th column contains data in array format. when I try to export it in CSV format; the data in 5th column is displayed as array. I don't want to show array in result.I want to show the 5th column data in column format.Is this possible in CSV fomat using PHP?

Thanks
Onkar Kubal

Comment: Can you please show us an example of exactly what you want your output to look like, and the code you've tried so far to make it look like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'll consider that the 5th field is a JSON array. If so, you might want `json_decode` on it first, and then encode it as a CSV.
You could use a proper lib, but just `join(',' $array)` might do it as well.